# What does 'thread-safe' mean in the context of collections or arrays in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm getting confused, I think by definitions.

Take, for example, the CopyOnWriteArrayList. The javadocs say "A thread-safe variant of ArrayList in which all mutative operations (add, set, and so on) are implemented by making a fresh copy of the underlying array ... This array never changes during the lifetime of the iterator, so interference is impossible"

But if I have a Person object that is mutable, and create a `CopyOnWriteArrayList<Person>`, surely there is nothing to stop another thread from modifying a field on my Person object while I am in the middle of iterating the array?

So when we talk about an object being thread-safe, is it always with the (implicit) qualification that of course, if you construct it with objects to which you retain the references, you can still change its state? Is it a question of what is considered ITS state, rather than the state of objects it happens to have close assocations with?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the documentation talks about thread safety of a collection, they mean thread safety of the collection itself, not the objects inside it. Obviously, a collection cannot make any guarantees about your mutable objects.

`CopyOnWriteArrayList` will protect as much as it can, i.e. its internal state. The state of your objects, on the other hand, is external to the collection, so it is not protected.